# Scikitlearn's labelencoder: How to add a "catch-all" miscellaneous encoding?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Scikitlearn's labelencoder on my current data.
I expect that my future data would sometimes have values for some of its variables that are not present in the current data - but I expect them to be a minority.

I would like to encode them via the labelencoder as a "misc" category, rather than have them fail the transformation. 
Of course, I can do this via non-direct methods, i.e. use a dictionary and replace all such unknown future values with a "misc" label (and fit the encoder to recognize it), but I wonder if there is a way to do so more directly, and without the hassle of maintaining such a dictionary for every feature I want to encode in such a manner.

Many thanks  :)

Comment: Perhaps try using `fit_transform` rather than just `transform`

Comment: Doing that would change the encoding, and would be highly problematic for any ML model I train on the original data.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, you want the missing categories in new data to be one separate catogory?

Comment: Yes, as if they were all categorized as 'miscellaneous'.

Comment: Do you currently have a `misc` label in your training data?

Comment: No; I could create one and use a dictionary to transform unfamiliar categories into it, but I wonder if there is a 'native' solution in Scikitlearn for the problem.

Comment: `LabelEnocder` as the name suggests is for `Labels` and not `Features`. There is a categorical encoder currently in the development version, which can handle values not seen before.

Comment: Very well, I will look it up.